# When you force a sign-in with AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(...), what actually is changed or updated in the TokenCache?

Tags: adal

I'm trying to figure out the life cycle of this object. I guess that when you sign in you get both authenticated and get an access token. When you fire AcquireTokenSilentAsync you are relying on the Authentication in the cache, hoping to get an access token. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AquireTokenAsync is used to acquire a token interactively in ADA.NET and once ADAL.NET has acquired token, it caches it, along with the refresh token.  When you use AcquireTokenSilentAsync next time when the application wants a token it first checks if an acceptable token is available is in the cache and not expired then it's returned. If there remains an expired token in cache, AcquireTokenSilentAsync use the cached refresh token to refresh the access token by requesting another access token and refresh token from Azure Active Directory. When No token is in the cache, AcquireTokenSilentAsync throws an AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException and the application will need to call AcquireTokenAsync to get the token.